# “He is now a happy man” & “he is now a man (who is) happy”

Tags: adjectives

Is there the difference between “he is now a happy man” and “he is now a man (who is) happy”?

I think the former means he is happy now but the latter can mean he isn’t happy now but it’s the general truth that he is happy.

And does the meaning change if I omit “who is” and move “happy” before the noun?

Comment: First of all, it's _a man who_, not _which_, but in any case the sentence is not idiomatic. You could say "He is a man who is _only_ happy when he is... (doing whatever his favourite pastime is)."

Comment: @Kate Bunting Does the meaning change if I omit “who is” and move happy before the noun?

Comment: @GatePending no.

Comment: That would be the correct version.